# Socket php to java when js event

Tags: javascript, java, php, sockets, web

So currently, I manage to communicate between php and java thanks to the socket. The problem is that once the java client is connected, I can't do anything anymore.

I would like that when a js event is triggered, information to the java client is transmitted.

How can I do that?

Thanks

My code php:

```
    $host = "0.0.0.0";
    $port = 6969;

    set_time_limit(0);

    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Create Error");

    $result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Bind Error");

    $result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Listener Error");

    $spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Accept Error");

    $input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Read Error");

    echo "Received: ".$input;

    $output = "Received";
    socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen($output)) or die("Write Error");
```

My java code:

```
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 6969);

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        writer.println("Test Message");
        writer.flush();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use REST unless you have a very specific use case .

Else you need to close socket (on client * php ) and stream  once you get the data.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html
read the explanation here, this will help you